# Logstash - Setting a timestamp from a JSON parsed object

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am having an issue with setting a timestamp from a JSON parse.

I have this string:

```
[{"orderNumber":"423523-4325-3212-4235-463a72e76fe8","externalOrderNumber":"reactivate_22d6ff0d8f55eb821be14df9d35505a6","operation":{"name":"CAPTURE","amount":134,"status":"SUCCESS","createdAt":"2015-05-11T09:14:30.969Z","updatedAt":{}}}]
```

I parse it as a json using this Logstash filter:

```
   grok {
        match => { "message" => "\[%{GREEDYDATA:firstjson}\]%{SPACE} \[%{GREEDYDATA:secondjson}\}]}]"}
        }
        json{
            source => "firstjson"
        }
        date {
            match => [ "operation.createdAt", "ISO8601"]
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "firstjson", "secondjson" ]
        }
    }
```

This creates a document inside the ElasticSearch. I have a field named operation.createdAt which is properly recognised as a date field. But for some reason, this line:

```
   date {
         match => [ "operation.createdAt", "ISO8601"]
        }
```

is not setting @timestamp field. Current @timestamp field is set at the moment of document insertion. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to nice people at [ES Logstash Community](https://discuss.elastic.co/c/logstash), I have found the answer.

Instead of:

```
date {
match => [ "operation.createdAt", "ISO8601"]
}
```

I use this:

```
date {
    match => [ "[operation][createdAt]", "ISO8601"]
}
```

and that properly extracts and parses the JSON time object.